# Moodle : is it possible to access user from javascript ONLY

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

My purpose is simply being able to retrieve basic user info (id, username, lastname, firstname) in javascript on ANY moodle page WITHOUT having to create a plugin.

I've seen that there is a javascript global variable in Moodle : `M` but no user info in there.

Is there a way to access user info (id at least) from a logged in user on any page only in javascript another way ?

I've tried the [generico filter](https://moodle.org/plugins/filter_generico) to create a block i would be able to retrieve information from

```
<span data-firstname="@@USER:firstname@@" data-lastname="@@USER:lastname@@" data-userid="@@USER:id@@" id="useriddata"></span>
```

But since i want it on any page, i've tried on the Moodle > Extra HTML textarea. Sadly it doesn't work since the HTML seems not to be filtered there.

Creating a plugin for such a small information seems wrong. What can i do ?

Answer (score 1):

You may request user info via [Web Services](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions) using ajax, e.g. `core_user_get_users_by_field`. You should, however, determine `userid` first, which can probably be retrieved from top menu links after signin (profile link etc.). But I would recommend to develop the plugin anyway

Comment: Is there no default Moodle cookie, no localStorage data having user id ?

Comment: There is, but cookies are not 100% reliable

Comment: If a user voluntarily deletes or block the cookies, that's his right, but moodle relies a bit on cookies to provide a better user experience, so in that case, i'm not concerned. If you can point me to an alternate solution, without php ( = without plugin), i'm all for it. For instance, if there was a tag with a data-userid attribute, accessible on ALL pages, it would be ok for me.